# Multidimensional Numpy ndarray to csv or pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a multidim ndarray with 60 columns and 40 rows with raw returns of stocks. When exporting to a csv file with nummpy.savetxt I got 40 rows but only one column. How can I export this matrix?

output when reading out the ndarray:

```
Out[88]: 
array([[-0.0038,  0.0002, -0.0017, ..., -0.0057,  0.0073,
         0.0025],
       [ 0.0006, -0.0021,  0.0103, ...,  0.0049, -0.0087,
         0.0123],
       [-0.0138, -0.0294,  0.0276, ...,  0.0474, -0.007 ,
         0.0031],
       ...,
       [-0.0049, -0.0232, -0.0356, ..., -0.0273,  0.0677,
        -0.0227],
       [ 0.002 , -0.0034, -0.0158, ...,  0.015 , -0.0002,
        -0.0044],
       [-0.0049,  0.0227,  0.0335, ...,  0.0025, -0.0222,
         0.0168]])
```

Comment: you should provide the output you are getting. We can't tell how to correct your problem if we don't know whats worng.

Comment: I will add it to the question

Comment: `numpy.savetxt` works for me. Better post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a delimiter. CSV files are default comma seperated.
E.g.

```
arr = np.random.rand(4,6)
np.savetxt('file.csv', arr, delimiter=',')`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to state the delimiter between values. By default it uses a space `' '`, but you will want `','`, which is default for csvs.